# Clarification about men being Munition Workers (on Birth Certificate)

Tags: birth-records, world-war-1, 1910s, wales, occupation

I am intrigued by this occupation on a birth certificate from 1918 in Llanelli, Carmarthenshire:

[image]

- Munitions Worker

According to this [article](http://www.photodetective.co.uk/Munitions.html#:%7E:text=While%20there%20was%20no%20uniform%20as%20such%2C%20munitions,are%20an%20indication%20of%20outdoor%2Cdirty%20or%20physical%20work.) it implies such a role would be performed by women.

Can anyone clarify?

---

Here is a little bit of background information about this father with respects to occupations:

- 1891 Census: 16 Steamer (Print Works)
- 1911 Marriage: 36 (but he said 26) Professional Athlete (sounds dodgy!)
- 1913 Birth / Baptism: 38 Trainer
- 1914 Birth / Baptism: 39 Football Club Trainer
- 1916 Baptism: 41 Foreman at Burry Port.
- 1918 Birth: 43 Munitions Worker (by now he has moved into a pub called Brecon Arms)
- 1919 Birth: 44 Licensed Victualler
- 1921 Census: 46 Licensed Victualler
- 1923 Birth: 48 Licensed Victualler
- Later years (up to 1935 when he died): Foreman at the Power Station in Llanelli.

This is first hand information about this father, in relation to his youngest son who was born in 1913:

> Some family info if you want - Uncle Cyril was born with club feet. The doctors wanted to amputate, but his dad refused. He worked on Uncle Cyril's feet himself with massage etc and fixed the problem.
> Must've done a good job since Uncle Cyril was allowed to serve in the navy!

So disability was in the family but I don't think the father was disabled. It gives a picture of his circumstances as a family man at the time of WW1.

Also, from my research you had to be between 18 - 45 to be enlisted and he was 43.